# how to reset bbox data of raphael text element

Tags: javascript, raphael

I'm trying to change the bbox data of raphael elements but it doesnt work.

I try to set

`textElement.attr("text","1");`

but it looks like to hold latest widest text width, what i assume to shrink bbox values to smaller text.

Obviously i'm missing something.

Comment: You're not giving us very much context to evaluate here.  Do you have a fiddle or a working example of the problem?  Even just a bit more of the code you're using would be illustrative.

Comment: agreed. But if you're trying to resize the element by assigning new values to the BBox, don't. Use .transform() to scale it.

Answer (score 0):

Raphael doesn't give you any control over elements' bounding boxes. Font elements' bounding boxes are limited to the width of the text. If you want to change the font size, just use the `font-size` attribute:

```
textElement.attr("font-size","12");
```